# Targeting li elements?

Tags: css

I have:

```
<ul>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a different width to each li.

I don't want to do it inline.

How can I target each li using CSS2 (not CSS3)?

Is there a way or do I need to give each li a class name?

Thanks

Comment: Each `li` individually or all of them the same?

Comment: Each li needs a different width

Comment: @beans: It looks silly but it is a pure CSS2 solution. **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/igisid/1/edit)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use comb css as you have to add class for each li in CSS
e:g-

```
li {}
li + li {}
li + li + li {}
li + li + li + li {}
li + li + li + li + li {}
```

Comment: Good. Only suggestion is to use `li:first-child` for the first li in each declaration. As it removes an uncessary amount of recursive processing of CSS. of course we are talking about millionths of a second. :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [nth-of-type](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype)

```
ul li:nth-of-type(1){} /* First */
ul li:nth-of-type(2){} /* Seconds */
```

and if you're worried about older browsers, there's a great [library](http://selectivizr.com) that adds CSS3 pseudo-classes to them.

The only CSS2 way would be to add classes to each LI.

**EDIT**

Actually the different classes per LI isn't the only CSS2 way. @Hashem Qolami comment to the original question has a decent CSS2 solution, but like he says, it looks a little silly.

Comment: In CSS2, you can do something like `li + li { /* styles for the 2nd li and on */ } li + li + li { /* reset the styles to the defaults, making the special styles work for the 2nd li only */ }` and so on. But this sort of "poor man's nth-child selector" is quite ineffective.

Comment: `The only CSS2 way would be to add classes to each LI` not true, check my comment ;)

Comment: Only saw that after I posted this answer. You are right, your solution is the best method without changing his HTML.

Comment: You can always amend your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure CSS2, you have to give them class names.  This could be accomplished with the `:nth-of-type()` psuedoclass selector but that is a CSS3 feature.

This would be very simple to do with jQuery as well (if you want to avoid relying on CSS3 but don't want to add class names to your markup).  This also would have the advantage of allowing you to dynamically change the widths as needed (rather than hard-coding property values as CSS classes).

Answer (score 0):

By "each li" do you mean each li element individually? if so, the nth selector might be your friend, though it is CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

You can give class names to all your li and set to display block, with float.

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UwsnA/):

```
li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}
li.small{
        width:50%;
}
li.big{
   width:100%; 
}
```